# Select data from multiline textbox, data is in dataset c#

Tags: c#

I have a multiline `textbox` and I want to allow the user to type into the multiline `textbox` looking for the data in the `dataset` and select the data stored in a `dataset`. The  matched should be displayed in a `datagridview`.

**Example**: In the database I have a column called "Name" if I type into the multiline `texbox` John in the first line and Nary in the second line then I should see these two names in the `datagridview`. I am open to using `dataview`, `dataset`, or `datagridview`.

Please help!!

Comment: This is what I've tried:

Comment: OK - please post the code for your form/page then thanks. We can then change it to get it working.